# Wildcard file requires in Ruby

Tags: ruby, rspec, filesystems, wildcard

As an example:

```
Dir[File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/support/**/*.rb"].each { |f| require f }
```

This is how RSpec requires all of the ruby files in the support directory and all subdirectories. I know this has to do with `"/**/*"`. What does this mean in Ruby? How does it work?

Answer (score 1):

`File.dirname(__FILE__)` is the directory where the file is. `**` and `*` are UNIX wildcards. Adding `"/support/**/*.rb` to the directory points to any file that ends with `.rb`, which is under an arbitrary depth under the sub-directory `support` under that directory.

Passing that to `Dir[]` gives the array of such files. `each` iterates over such files, and `require` loads each file.

Answer (score 0):

i believe that the `/**/` part means Any directory , and the `*.rb` means any file that ends with .rb extention, regardless of it's name.

so, basically, you are getting any .rb file that are in any folder in

`#{current_dir}/support/#{any_dir}/#{any_file_with_extention.rb}`